# Report Orientation in Jasperreport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report this is the details as follow:
- the paper size is A5
- the orientation based on the xml file is Landscape but when printing, the output is portrait.

Then when I download the file (I used adobe reader) when I go to print preview I selecting the Landscape, the report is not change to landscape format. I am new in this scenarios Please Help me out

thanks.

Comment: you can try change pageWidth and pageHeight in your report, example pageHeight = 400 and pageWidth = 300

Comment: alright I try that one. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not sufficient to change `pageHeight` and `pageWidth`.

Additionally you have to set `orientation="Landscape"` in the top-level `jasperReport` tag. Otherwise it could be that some tools will always re-set your report back to `portrait` and ignore the `width` and `height` settings.

This option is also available in Jaspersoft Studio:

[image: Page Orientation setting in Jaspersoft Studio]

Comment: It is not working either. Neither I go to LETTER format

Comment: Same problem here.... landscape reports print to portrait. Export to file is perfect though (luckily!)

- Mario